# How to change image of ImageView inside custom adapter when click button on main activity?

Tags: android

Now, I set image for each item `listView` from `MainActivity` class

```
private void setBackground(int position, int drawable){
    ViewListItem item = adapter.getItem(itemID);

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            item.ivPlayerAnswer1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPlayerAnswer1);
            item.ivPlayerAnswer1.setImageResource(drawable);
            break;
        case 1:
            item.ivPlayerAnswer2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPlayerAnswer2);
            item.ivPlayerAnswer2.setImageResource(drawable);
            break;
        case 2:
            item.ivPlayerAnswer3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPlayerAnswer3);
            item.ivPlayerAnswer3.setImageResource(drawable);
            break;
        case 3:
            item.ivPlayerAnswer4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPlayerAnswer4);
            item.ivPlayerAnswer4.setImageResource(drawable);
            break;
    }
}
```

**`onClick`** method to get the `button` clicked will be set background for image of position (`image1: position = 0, image2: position = 1,` ...)

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.ivChoice1:
            setBackground(position, intRes[0]);
            break;
        case R.id.ivChoice2:
            setBackground(position, intRes[1]);
            break;
        case R.id.ivChoice3:
            setBackground(position, intRes[2]);
            break;
        case R.id.ivChoice4:
            setBackground(position, intRes[3]);
            break;
        case R.id.ivChoice5:
            setBackground(position, intRes[4]);
            break;
        case R.id.ivChoice6:
            setBackground(position, intRes[5]);
            break;
    }
    position++; //postion (0, 1, 2, 3...) of each image on item of listview (position is from left to right)
    if(position > 3){
        itemID++; //id of listview 0, 1, 2, 3...
        position = 0;
    }
}
```

**`getView`** method like below:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

    ViewListItem item; //item of listview
    if(view==null)
    {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);
        item = new ViewListItem(this.context);

        item.ivSuggestAnswer1 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivSuggestAnswer1);
        item.ivSuggestAnswer2 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivSuggestAnswer2);
        item.ivSuggestAnswer3 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivSuggestAnswer3);
        item.ivSuggestAnswer4 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivSuggestAnswer4);
        item.ivPlayerAnswer1 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivPlayerAnswer1);
        item.ivPlayerAnswer2 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivPlayerAnswer2);
        item.ivPlayerAnswer3 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivPlayerAnswer3);
        item.ivPlayerAnswer4 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.ivPlayerAnswer4);

        view.setTag(item);
    } else {
        item = (ViewListItem)view.getTag();
    }

    return view;
  }
}
```

This only set for first item `listView`, the other item of `listView` can not set for them.

Comment: where is the list?Is it on Main Activity?

Comment: yes, and i transmitted it to custom adapter with contractor method, public MyAdapter(Context c, List<Item> list).

Comment: Thank Aris Panayiotou, I have found a solution for myself.

Comment: First, i get one item of listview (item is a View)
Next, i set value for child of that item
End, it for result as my desired.